# What is the difference between Pollen and Coordicide?

Tags: iota-network, coordicide

Are they two different names to describe the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Coordicide** refers to a goal on the IOTA roadmap, namely to remove the coordinator and create a network that works safely and reliably without it.

**Pollen** is the codename for the first phase of coordicide, which refers to creating a network for testing a promising coordicide strategy which will hopefully be used later. The later phases are called **Nectar** and **Honey**.

See [the coordicide roadmap](https://roadmap.iota.org/coordicide) and [this blog post](https://blog.iota.org/iota-2-0-introducing-pollen-nectar-and-honey-de7b9c4c8199/) for the definition of the coordicide phases.

Answer (score 3):

The naming was changed yesterday to IOTA 2.0 DevNet (Development Network). Please read this blog post:
https://blog.iota.org/path-towards-full-decentralization-with-iota-2-0/